# How to find GCP availability (for pre-emptible GPUs)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, provisioning

I recently moved zones to us-central1-a in order to use pre-emptible T4 GPUs.  I had my quota adjusted up to 1024, but only 12 instances will start.  While frustrating to learn that GCP is oversubscribed, I understand these things happen and stackoverflow questions bare this out.  It might have been nice for the rep increasing my quota to warn me of this.

Is there any way to see where there is current availability?  Or even a historical record of oversubscription?

Comment: Are uou sure you are not bumping into some other quota? I've used gcp with 30k+ cores concurrently and have learnt that there is a whole lot of quotas you might run into not related to the cpu or gpu

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  Yeah, I checked my quotas page and nothing seems maxed out.  I was able to start a few dozen 32-core machines (while my GPUs are on 8-core machines), so I don't think I'm RAM/CPU constrained.

Comment: If you have stackdriver logging turned on, there should be events published to the logging console that you can try to filter on. If they are failing to start because of a resource shortage, i would expect a message to be shown there

Comment: Please update your question with discovered messages at the logging console.